# Is there a way to print additional text to a textfield when detail is overflowed

Tags: jasper-reports

I was wondering if anyone can think of a way add additional text to a detail when it is printed again in due to overflow.

For example, if a textfield has `isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"` set, and is printed again on the a second column, is there any variable that can be accessed that would determine if overflow has been set.

An example might look like

`<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SOME_FIELD} + ($V{OVERFLOW_COUNT} > 0)?" (Continued)":""]]></textFieldExpression>`

And would append '(Continued)' to the field if it is printed multiple times.

Is this functionality possible within JasperReports?

Comment: As I know, there is no such flag at JasperReports engine